# serving grunt managed UI in sinatra based web-app

Tags: javascript, ruby, gruntjs, sinatra, bower

I'm in early stage of web-app development, where:

- API: ruby + sinatra (using bundler)
- UI: html+js (angular + yeoman => grunt+bower)

dir layout:

- fooApp - contains API
- fooApp/ui - contains UI

I can nicely unit test these separately.

Up to now, I used for manual testing:

- `bundle exec rackup` (backend)
- `grunt serve` (for UI)

However I'm in a phase when I need to serve the UI from sinatra. And here I'm stuck. How should I proceed? How should I reference grunt/bower managed stuff from sinatra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it myself: [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) does proxying for me during development.

For those interested, following did it for me:

1. in `fooApp/ui` had to install it:

   ```
   npm install grunt-connect-proxy --save-dev
   ```
2. afterwards added to `Gruntfile.js`:

   ```
   // load the proxy.
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-connect-proxy');
   var proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;

   ...

   proxies: [
           {
               context: '/api',
               host: 'localhost',
               port: 9292
           }
       ],
   livereload: {
   ...
   ```